# Send message using aws lex and aws sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, chatbot, amazon-sns, aws-lex

i'm building chatbot using aws services(lambda, lex, and dynamodb). Im at the point where i need to inform user of dynamodb table update through the aws lex. I planned to do that with aws simple notification service but i'm not sure is that even possible and if it is how can i do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want explicitly to send DynamoDB records to a user (perhaps a DevOps or technical support?), then use [DynamoDB Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/) to achieve that.

If not, I would recommend sending that particular change to a SNS topic, which you will have 2 subscribed services. One will save the data in DynamoDB, the other will send the message to the user.

In order to send the message to the user, it should not go through Lex. Just reuse the channel (sms, skype...) where the user is engaging with Lex and send a message there. Think of Lex more of request-response, not actively sending messages.